# Design of a multi-level abstraction software

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm working on designing a piece of software now, that has a few levels of abstraction. This might be the most complex piece of code I've ever started designing, and it has a requirement for easy upgrading, so I'm wanting to make sure I'm on the right track before I even start coding anything.

Essentially, there will be 3 main levels of classes. These two classes will need to talk with each other.

The first is the input source data. There are currently 2 main types of input data, which produce similar, but not identical output. The main goal of these classes will be to get the data from the two difference sources and convert it into a common interface, for use in the rest of the program.

The second set will be an adapter for an external library. The library has been periodically updated, and I have no reason to suspect that it will not continue to be updated throughout the years. Most likely, each upgrade will remain very similar to the previous one, but there might be some small changes made to support a new library version. This level will be responsible for taking the inputs, and formatting them for a use of an output class.

The last class is the outputs. I don't think that multiple versions will be required for this, but there will need to be at least two different output directories specified. I suspect the easiest thing to do would be to simply pass in an output directory when the output class is created, and that is the only level of abstraction required. This class will be frequently updated, but there is no requirement to support multiple versions.

Comment: Do you really need classes for e.g. the input and output? Remember the golden rule for classes; If your class has two methods, and one of them is `__init__`, its not a class but a function.

Comment: The inputs and outputs are actually complex sets, ie, they will be inputting and outputting completely different formats, different files, etc. It will be more than just a simple function.

Comment: Just keep http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ in mind. Especially "Simple is better than complex".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the code as follows, essentially following a [bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), but with multiple abstraction layers.

The input class will be the abstraction. The currently two different means of getting output will be the two different concrete classes, and more concrete classes can be added if required.

The wrapper class will be a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Most of the code should be common between the various implementations, so this should work well to handle minute differences.

The output class will be included as a part of the implementor class. There isn't a pattern really required, as only one version will ever be required for this class. Also, the implementor will likely be a singleton.